# CSS Stretching Elements

Tags: html, css

I have html like below

```
<div>
   <div class="left">
   </div>
   <div class="center">
   </div>
   <div class="right">
   </div>
</div>


.left
{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-right: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
}

.center
{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 171px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width:895px;
}

.right
{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DEDFE8;
  border-left: 5px solid #BDC1DE;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 276px;
}
```

when the center panel stretches the right and left panels stay at there height of 100%

Is there a way of stretching the right and left panels when the center panel stretches.

### Edit

When the center panel consists of html controls that make the center div expand more than the min-height of 100% the left and right panels do not expand and these panels have different colors and borders and the page doesnt look right as you can see gaps after the when right and left panels do not expand and the center panel does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set the outer div that contains the divs below with width:100%, position:absolute and min-height:100%

then change the css to this

```
.left
{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border-right: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
}

.center
{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 171px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width:895px;
}

.right
{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DEDFE8;
  border-left: 5px solid #BDC1DE;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 276px;
}

<div class="width:100%;position:absolute;min-height:100%">
   <div class="left">
   </div>
   <div class="center">
   </div>
   <div class="right">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like the equal height columns from www.ejeliot.com

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/s8uLG/3/

You set your container up with overflow set to hidden, then on each div add negative margin-bottom and equal positive padding-bottom.

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
#container div { float: left; background: #ccc; width: 200px; margin-bottom: -2000px; padding-bottom: 2000px; }
#container .col2 { background: #eee; }

<div id="container">
   <div>
        <p>Content 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Faux Columns is also good and probably easier to set up but if you're really dead against using an image this is a pretty good method.

Comment: You can add a third or more columns in by just sticking another div in after .col2

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, you mean you want them to expand *vertically*. There are a few ways to do this, but my favorite is [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

You basically put a background with your column colors on the whole containing div and it gives the illusion that all three columns are the same height.

You're still going to want to workout your positioning issues. As I mentioned before, `position:absolute` should be used with either `top, left, bottom` or `right`. Or, instead of absolute positioning, you can use `floats`. You can't use both :)